# How to interpret correlation coefficient values of many experiments together?

Tags: correlation, entropy

In a research article which I was reading I found that, the authors calculated the correlation coefficients between two variables.

The two variables are “absolute entropy” and “change in entropy”. They calculated this for 10 data sets (say, for 10 different materials). The correlation coefficients varied between 0.74 and 0.98. Then they concluded saying, there is a roughly 25% loss in the absolute entropy.

I could not understand why that is the case?

Comment: Which article, and how was the absolute entropy formulated

Comment: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/pro.5560041101 -- this is the article. Please look at the 'Absolute Entropy' section in page 6

Comment: including those two in the question by pressing edit will probably help get a response

Comment: Done! I didn't find 'Absolute entropy'. Thanks you for the suggestion!

Comment: I meant include the formula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could just be the result of mathematical coupling. The correlation between a variable and the change in that variable, it can be severely distorted.

We can easily construct an example. We simulate a variable, `ent1` and then another, `ent2` which changes by 25% then we calculate the correlation between `ent1` and the change:

```
> set.seed(1)
> ent1 <- rnorm(100, 50, 10)
> ent2 <- ent1 * 1.25 + rnorm(100)
> cor(ent1, ent2 - ent1)
[1] 0.9197477
```

and we obtain a correlation of 92% even though the real change was 25%, as per the data in the question.

Comment: Thanks Robert! That's exactly what I needed.